# File is not `gofmt`-ed with `-s`: why is this happening and how to resolve it?

Tags: go, github-actions, linter, gofmt

We use a linter (for Golang) that run through a Github Actions workflow every time we open or update a Pull Request on [our repository](https://github.com/ZupIT/ritchie-cli).

It recently started to return the following [error](https://github.com/ZupIT/ritchie-cli/runs/3508741503#step:4:15):

`` File is not `gofmt`-ed with `-s` (gofmt) ``

After what happened in [this other PR](https://github.com/ZupIT/ritchie-cli/pull/1022/files) to the file `pkg/api/api/go`.

*(EDIT: link added to evaluate and eventually reproduce the error)*

**Evidences:**

[image: original commit]

[image: linter output]

**I would like to understand what was the source of this error, as well as how to resolve it?**

Comment: I fixed it by running: `golangci-lint run --fix`

Comment: the solution [here](https://bluehive.medium.com/how-to-fix-file-is-not-gofumpt-ed-gofumpt-error-bca04d64229f) fixed my issue.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

##### Source of the error

It seems this error can be returned when **the file is not properly formatted according to Go rules**.

*For example: If you accidentally used tab indentation rather than spaces.*

*EDIT: **blackgreen's answer** gives more accurate details about the source of the error*

---

##### How to resolve it

You can use the following Go command:

`gofmt -s -w <path_to_file>.go`

... then commit the code.

*Note that in my case: `gofmt -w pkg/api/api.go` was enough to resolve the problem (without the `-s` flag, which I found strange as the error specifically asked for the `-s`).*

[Source 1](https://www.cloudnotes.io/file-is-not-gofmt-ed-with-s/) + [Source 2](https://github.com/gojp/goreportcard/issues/202)

Comment: If you found a way to demonstrate the problem you should add it to the question; that will probably get it reopened.

Comment: Anybody knows if there is a way to automatically enable this in jetbrains goland, so the command don't need to be executed ?

Comment: @Mb175 Configure it to reformat your code on save and then to use go fmt on reformatting code in the code style section: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47735678/goland-how-to-use-gofmt

Answer (score 8):

The `-s` flag in `gofmt` has nothing to do with formatting. It's about [simplifying](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/gofmt#hdr-The_simplify_command) the code:

> Try to simplify code (after applying the rewrite rule, if any).

The warning you see comes from the linter [`golangci-lint`](https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint). Since you claim to have fixed the error by running `gofmt -w`, the presence of the hint "with `-s`" may be due to this bug: https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/issues/513.

The linked issue was fixed in 2019 and released with [`v1.17.0`](https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/releases/tag/v1.17.0). You might want to check if your pipeline is using an older version.

Assuming that your file `pkg/api/api.go` triggered the warning just because it was not formatted, `gofmt -w` solves the issue because `-w` overwrites the file:

> If a file's formatting is different from gofmt's, overwrite it with gofmt's version.

Comment: how come the formatting went different? I have like 100 of files in the repo which I just checked out, is the only solution to `gofmt` on each file individually?
I am using windows system in case if thats screwing the file formatting.

Comment: @ObaidMaroof you don't have to reformat each file individually. You can supply directory paths to `gofmt` or use shell expansion